# When to use "multipliable" vs. "multiplicable"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, mathematics

I'm writing an application that allows users to select whether certain mathematical elements have certain properties. These properties are things such as "divisible", "addable", "subtractable" etc.

I was therefore wondering which of the words listed in the title I should use to describe the attribute where something can be multiplied. I'm not sure which one is the appropriate one to use when describing mathematical properties. The Oxford dictionary does not make a notice on which one is best suited for this purpose.

If they are the same, I would be interested in knowing which one would be the more popular option among native English speakers.

Comment: multipliable seems closest to the others(divisible, addable, subtractable) . "Multiplicable" means to me applicable or in many places or having many substitutes?  But... don't trust me alone on that one

Comment: Don't forget *multiplicative*...

Comment: Please provide an example of something that isn't multipliable.  I'm just not with you yet.

Comment: @Drew Can you say that something is multiplicative when it can be multiplied by another value? I'm not sure, I'm not a native speaker but it sounds weird.

Comment: @aparente001 There isn't really anything that isn't multipliable per se, but that doesn't mean that it cannot be described as such.

Comment: @Qub1: I wasn't answering the question. Just pointing out that there are several adjectives having to do with multiples and multiplication. In math, for example, the multiplicative inverse of a number x is 1/x.

Comment: @aparente001 "Banana" and "potato" are not multipliable.  And 16384 and 16384 are not multipliable in 16-bit arithmetic.

Comment: I have seen both terms used, and at least once recall an article that agonized over which term was best.  (I don't recall their decision.)

Comment: @HotLicks - The number of bananas can be multiplied.  If you think of "be fruitful and multiply," I suppose potatoes could multiply.  You cut them up in the spring, one eye to each piece, put them in the ground or the compost heap, and a few months later, each piece has become a bunch of new potatoes!  But I think banana plants have a strange way of making new banana plants, I can't remember what.  It was something unusual.  Anyway, without more context, I think we'd need to toss a coin.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, both words are synonyms (have the same definition):

> **multipliable** *adj* able to be multiplied.

> **multiplicable** *adj* able to be multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

Multipliable = multiplicable, addable = addible.

You could toss a coin.  If you want me to choose, I'd need more context.

You are right not to get off track with *multiplicative*.